# System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, exception

I am hoping one of you will be able to kindly assist me with an error I am receiving in my code. Please note, I have limited experience, so an explanation would be appreciated! :)

When I clicked on my  "Add New Product" (btnSubmit), I receive the following error message:

> An exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Code:
             private void SaveProductPhoto()
             {
                 if (PPhoto.PostedFile != null)
            {
                string PName = PPhoto.PostedFile.FileName.ToString();
                       string fileExtension =           System.IO.Path.GetExtension(PPhoto.FileName);

```
                 }
            //Save images into Images folder
            else
            {
                PPhoto.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/PImg/" + PName));

            }
        }
    }
```

My code failed at this line :

```
UploadProductPhoto.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/ProductImages/" + PName));
```

Comment: At which line it failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line is incorrect :

```
UploadProductPhoto.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/ProductImages/" + fileName));
```

It is incorrect because you are using `Server.MapPath` about inexisting path `"~/ProductImages/" + fileName`

To fix it you must first get the directory path where you want to put the image then combnine it with the file name like this : `System.Io.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/ProductImages/"), fileName)`

Notice that Server.MapPath only contains `"~/ProductImages/"`

At the end you will have something like the code below.

```
UploadProductPhoto.SaveAs(
     System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/ProductImages/"), fileName)
);
```

Comment: Sorry, laptop is posting weird. It reads "An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format." I get this message after "ProductImageUrl = "~/ProductImages/" + UploadProductPhoto.FileName,
            };"

Comment: It is a another error. Not related to the first error message in your question. It seems you want to generate Image URL of your tmage then just use the following line => `ProductImageUrl = string.Format("/ProductImages/{0}",  UploadProductPhoto.FileName);` 
Notice I haven't use the "~" character

Comment: Thank you again for replying! I have changed the line of code and still get the same error message! :(

Comment: I think  the exception is not thrown for the line you just show me.
Make sure that conversion to integer from a string variable is correct. 
I mean the FormatException maybe came because you are converting a text to integer and the text is not correct. Check that please.

Comment: Hi @CodeNotFound. I think its ok, but my coding ability is not the best. I have updated the original post with the "Shopping Cart" logic for adding a new product? Does this help with diagnosing the issue. Thanks again! Jack

Comment: Please close this question by accepting this answer because it solve the firrst problem. After that create anotger thread for the new issue. And I will help you there.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the path and file if it is already exists. you can see you are getting error "Could not find a part of the path '\stu-storage2\user-area\3\mj350\Desktop\CWWebsite\CWWebsite\ProductImages\stu-storage2\user-area\3\mj350\Desktop\1.jpg'"

it means file or file path is wrong